# Is the order complex of open Bruhat intervals polytopal?

Tags: posets, coxeter-groups, bruhat-order

Let $P$ be the Bruhat order of a Coxeter group, and let $s<t$ in
$P$. The set $\Delta(s,t)$ of all chains of the open interval $(s,t)$
(called the *order complex* of $(s,t)$) is a simplicial complex. By
the work of Björner and Wachs, the geometric realization of
$\Delta(s,t)$ is homeomorphic to a sphere. What is known about when
$\Delta(s,t)$ is polytopal, i.e., is the boundary complex of a
simplicial (convex) polytope?

Comment: Related question: Bjorner-Wachs show that [s,t] is the face lattice of a regular cellular ball. Is that cell complex ever polytopal?

Comment: @SamHopkins: there is some information at https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05011.pdf. In particular, $[s,t]$ is polytopal if and only if it is a lattice if and only if it is a boolean algebra.